# How to set properly URI to Metro App developed VS2012 Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, uri, windows-8.1

I have a metro app developed with Visual Studio 2012, I set up the URI this way:

[image]

and this is code added in default.js

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
         } else {
         }


        //Handles URI activation
        WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", onActivatedHandler, false);

        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(init));
    }
};




function onActivatedHandler(eventArgs) {
    if (eventArgs.detail.kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocol) {
        // TODO: Handle URI activation.


        // The received URI is eventArgs.detail.uri.rawUri

    }
}
```

then I open my webBrowser and I type on address textfield:

```
e-camera:///
```

it works good (when the app is running background) but if it is first time open, it crashes
I think I need to set something on function onActivatedHandler() to see if application is not initialized, any help I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the [Association Launching Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec), it seems you are only handling one of the three possible cases that can launch your app, i.e., you are handling :

- Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch

But not handling:

- Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocol **<-- You need this.**
- Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.file

Try this:

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        // ...
    }
    else if (args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocol) {
        // Receives URI
        var arg = args.detail.uri;

        // Handles URI activation
        WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", onActivatedHandler, false);
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(init));
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it should be args.detail.uri in your case. I'll fix it. The sample requires VS2013 :( but if you look at the code, the logic should be similar.